# why not panic when task timeout?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

I set the timeout to 1s, but the task executes to 3s, but no panic occurs.

#code

```
    #[should_panic]
    fn test_timeout() {
        let rt = create_runtime();
        let timeout_duration = StdDuration::from_secs(1);
        let sleep_duration = StdDuration::from_secs(3);

        let _guard = rt.enter();

        let timeout = time::timeout(timeout_duration, async {
            log("timeout running");
            thread::sleep(sleep_duration);
            log("timeout finsihed");
            "Ding!".to_string()
        });

        rt.block_on(timeout).unwrap();
    }
```

Comment: I assume the timeout fails because there is nothing asynchronous in your function. Try `tokio::time::sleep` instead of `thread::sleep`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `thread::sleep` in asynchronous code [is almost always wrong](https://ryhl.io/blog/async-what-is-blocking/).

Conceptually, the timeout works like this:

- `tokio` spawns a timer which would wake up after the specified duration.
- `tokio` spawns your future. If it returns `Poll::Ready`, timer is thrown away and the future succeeds. If it returns `Poll::Pending`, `tokio` waits for the next event, i.e. for wakeup of either your future or the timer.
- If the future wakes up, `tokio` polls it again. If it returns `Poll::Ready` - again, timer is thrown away, future succeeds.
- If the timer wakes up, `tokio` polls the future one last time; if it's still `Poll::Pending`, it times out and is not polled anymore, and `timeout` returns an error.

In your case, however, future do *not* return `Poll::Pending` - it blocks inside the `thread::sleep`. So, even though the timer could fire after one second has passed, `tokio` has no way to react - it waits for the future to return, future returns only after the thread is unblocked, and, since there's no `await` inside the block, it returns `Poll::Ready` - so the timer isn't even checked.

To fix this, you're expected to use [`tokio::time::sleep`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/time/fn.sleep.html) for any pauses inside async code. With it, the future times out properly. To illustrate this claim, let's see the self-contained example equivalent to your original code:

```
use core::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::timeout;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let timeout_duration = Duration::from_secs(1);
    let sleep_duration = Duration::from_secs(3);

    timeout(timeout_duration, async {
        println!("timeout running");
        std::thread::sleep(sleep_duration);
        println!("timeout finsihed");
        "Ding!".to_string()
    })
    .await
    .unwrap_err();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=eea28b4b6e4eb6179fc34df1a359f86e)

As you've already noticed, this fails - `unwrap_err` panics when called on `Ok`, and timeout returns `Ok` since the future didn't time out properly.

But when replacing `std::thread::sleep(...)` with `tokio::time::sleep(...).await`...

```
use core::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::timeout;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let timeout_duration = Duration::from_secs(1);
    let sleep_duration = Duration::from_secs(3);

    timeout(timeout_duration, async {
        println!("timeout running");
        tokio::time::sleep(sleep_duration).await;
        println!("timeout finsihed");
        "Ding!".to_string()
    })
    .await
    .unwrap_err();
}
```

...we get the expected behavior - [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3021babca5173843de7ee61e384777a4).